# Rails 4.2: Eager-loading has_many relation with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Let's say I have a relation in Rails to a table that uses STI like:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base; end

class Car < Vehicle; end

class Truck < Vehicle; end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  has_many :trucks
  has_many :vehicles
end
```

... and I want to load a Person and all of its cars and trucks in one query. This doesn't work:

```
# Generates three queries
p = Person.includes([:cars, trucks]).first
```

... and this is close, but no luck here:

```
# Preloads vehicles in one query
p = Person.includes(:vehicles).first
# and this has the correct class (Car or Truck)
p.vehicles.first
# but this still runs another query
p.cars
```

I could do something like this in person.rb:

```
def cars
  vehicles.find_all { |v| v.is_a? Car }
end
```

but then `Person#cars` isn't a collection proxy anymore, and I *like* collection proxies.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

EDIT: Adding this to Person gives me the items I want in arrays with one query; it's really pretty close to what I want:

```
def vehicle_hash
  @vehicle_hash ||= vehicles.group_by {|v|
    v.type.tableize
  }
end

%w(cars trucks).each do |assoc|
  define_method "#{assoc}_from_hash".to_sym do
    vehicle_hash[assoc] || []
  end
end
```

and now I can do `Person.first.cars_from_hash` (or find a better name for my non-synthetic use case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `includes`, it stores those loaded records in the `association_cache`, which you can look at in the console. When you do `p = Person.includes(:vehicles)`, it stores those records as an association under the key `:vehicles`. It uses whatever key you pass it in the includes.

So then when you call `p.cars`, it notices that it doesn't have a `:cars` key in the `association_cache` and has to go look them up. It doesn't realize that Cars are mixed into the `:vehicles` key.

To be able to access cached cars as either through `p.vehicles` OR `p.cars` would require caching them under both of those keys.

And what it stores is not just a simple array—it's a Relation. So you can't just manually store records in the Hash.

Of the solutions you proposed, I think including each key is probably the simplest—code-wise. `Person.includes(:cars, :trucks)` 3 SQL statements aren't so bad if you're only doing it once per request.

If performance is an issue, I think the simplest solution would be a lot like what you suggested. I would probably write a new method `find_all_cars` instead of overwriting the relation method.

Although, I would probably overwrite `vehicles` and allow it to take a type argument:

```
def vehicles(sti_type=nil)
  return super unless sti_type
  super.find_all { |v| v.type == sti_type }
end
```

**EDIT**

You can get `vehicles` cached by Rails, so you probably can just rely on that. Your `define_method`s could also do:

```
%w(cars trucks).each do |assoc|
  define_method "preloaded_#{assoc}" do
    klass = self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.detect { |assn| assn.name.to_s == assoc }.klass
    vehicles.select { |a| a.is_a? klass }
  end
end
```

Even if you don't use `includes`, the first time you call it, it will cache the association—because you're `select`ing, not `where`ing. You still won't get a Relation back, of course.

It's not really that pretty, but I like that it's contained to one method that doesn't depend on any other ones.

Comment: Yeah, the performance hit may be notable; I'm doing this for six STI classes on each of two parents. Hm... what would be involved in ginning up actual Relations for the assocation_cache?

Comment: I've added a variant of your solution up top. Vaguely sane? Curious, though: why would you change vehicles to take the STI type? (In my case, I'm generally going to load all of my STI types for each request.)

Comment: Looks about as good as any. Although you still don't get a relation as a result. I was looking for a solution that added the fewest methods and least amount of complexity. Your solution seems to add just a bit too much for my taste. I'll add an edit too.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I really wanted to be able to somehow tell AR "load all of these STI subclasses with one query" and get proper relations, which I guess is not really a thing.